# unable to step into a WCF service application

Tags: .net, wcf

I am trying to send messages from my client application to my WCF service but I am not able to step into the service operation in order to debug.

I am hosting the service in another project using installer and the service starts perfectly.I can access the service URL once I run the host application.

I have a service application with this configuration:

```
    system.serviceModel>
        <client/>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="meta">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="meta" name="InboundMessage.Service.Operator">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="InboundMessage.Service.IOperator"/>
            <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
            <host>
              <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress = "http://localhost/InboundMessage.Service/" />
              </baseAddresses>
            </host>
          </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="UNI.Endpoint.Basic"/>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>

      </system.serviceModel>
```

Service Operation:

```
      IOperation
      [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://xx/MessageService/", SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
    public interface IOperator
    {
    [OperationContract(Action = "http://xx/MessageService/GetMessage")]
     byte GetMessage(string AppId, string Message);

}


   [ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://xx/MessageService/",    IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
      public class Operator : IOperator
       {
    public byte GetMessage(string AppId, string Message)
    { //
    // returns byte 
}
```

My client is a webform and it has this configuration:

```
   <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="InboundMessage.Service.IOperator" name="InboundMessage.Service.Operator">
      <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="InboundMessage.Service.IOperator" bindingConfiguration="largeMessageHttpBinding">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost/InboundMessage.Service/"/>
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>

    <bindings>
         <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="largeMessageHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="100000"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="InboundMessage.Service.IOperator">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
      <behavior name="SessionServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

what am i missing? Thank you

Comment: This might sound like a silly question, but you do have your breakpoints in the project hosting the service, correct? You can't step into the service code from the client project.

Comment: @DanielSimpkins I have breakpoints in the Operator service and also in the host project

Comment: @DanielSimpkins I am unable to step into the service from client

Comment: See if this link helps. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157685.aspx

Comment: @DanielSimpkins thanks but I already have multiple project selected

Answer (score 0):

Initial observations:

- Your service is configured with basicHttpBinding, but your client is configured with wsHttpBinding.

More information needed:

- Is your client able to get a correct response from the service, or are you getting an exception?
- When you say "I am hosting the service in another project using installer," what do you mean by "installer?"
- Is your service hosted in Cassini, IIS Express, or IIS?

Comment: I will check the initial observation .

Comment: no my client is not getting any response or error. I am hosting my the service in a console application and it has a installer class added to it. the host application is in the same solution as my client and service

Comment: If your client is getting neither a response nor an error, then is it getting a timeout exception?  It must be getting at least that; it can't just sit there "hung" all day waiting for a response.  Perhaps you are making the WCF call from a background thread or Task.  In that case your foreground thread could be entirely unaware that an exception was thrown.  Consider placing a try/catch(Exception ex) around the client-call code, and set a breakpoint to see if an exception is caught.  Either that, or try ctrl-alt-e in Visual Studio, where you can configure catching first-time CLR exceptions.

Comment: Also,  And I still don't understand how the "installer" relates to your service.  For example, is your installer creating an NT service which is performing self-hosting with the ServiceHost class?  Or does your console application directly launch ServiceHost?